# Get dag_run context in Airflow TaskFlow task

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-taskflow

My dag is started with configuration JSON:

```json
{"foo" : "bar"}
```

I have a Python operator which uses this value:

```
my_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id="my_task",
    op_kwargs={"foo": "{{ dag_run.conf['foo'] }}"},
    python_callable=lambda foo: print(foo))
```

I’d like to replace it with a TaskFlow task…

```py
@task
def my_task:
  # how to get foo??
```

How can I get a reference to context, dag_run, or otherwise get to the configuration JSON from here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several ways to do this using the TaskFlow API:

```py
import datetime

from airflow.decorators import dag, task
from airflow.operators.python import get_current_context


@dag(start_date=datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1), schedule=None)
def so_75303816():
    @task
    def example_1(**context):
        foo = context["dag_run"].conf["foo"]
        print(foo)

    @task
    def example_2(dag_run=None):
        foo = dag_run.conf["foo"]
        print(foo)

    @task
    def example_3():
        context = get_current_context()
        foo = context["dag_run"].conf["foo"]
        print(foo)

    @task
    def example_4(params=None):
        foo = params["foo"]
        print(foo)

    example_1()
    example_2()
    example_3()
    example_4()


so_75303816()
```

Depending on your needs/preference, you can use one of the following examples:

- `example_1`: You get all task instance context variables and have to extract "foo".
- `example_2`: You explicitly state via arguments you want only `dag_run` from the task instance context variables. Note that you have to default arguments to `None`.
- `example_3`: You can also fetch the task instance context variables from inside a task using `airflow.operators.python.get_current_context()`.
- `example_4`: DAG run context is also available via a variable named "params".

For more information, see https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial/taskflow.html#accessing-context-variables-in-decorated-tasks and https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html#variables.